# DiscordJS, Delete previous embed message after receiving slash command

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I have a bot that sends an embed message after receiving a `/xyz` with something like this

```
    client.on("interactionCreate", async (interaction) => {
      if (!interaction.isCommand()) return;
    
      const { commandName } = interaction;
    
      if (commandName === "xyz") {

         const embed = {
          title: "title of embed message",
          description: "description of embed message",
          ....
          }

    await interaction.channel.send({ embeds: [embed] });  
}
```

I would like to know how to delete the previous embed messages the bot sent, before sending a new one after receiving the `/xyz` command

Comment: So you want to delete the embed sent before, by the same command?

Comment: that is correct

Answer (score 1):

Set a variable on the outer scope that you will assign when sending the embeds. Delete it whenever the command is run

```js
let embedBefore;
client.on("interactionCreate", async (interaction) => {
      if (!interaction.isCommand()) return;
    
      const { commandName } = interaction;
    
      if (commandName === "xyz") {
         await embedBefore?.delete().catch(console.error) // delete the embed, catch and log error if thrown
         const embed = {
          title: "title of embed message",
          description: "description of embed message"
          }
        // assign embedBefore to the sent embed; Note: this is not an interaction reply
        embedBefore = await interaction.channel.send({ embeds: [embed] });
    }
})
```

The embed will stay there when the bot is restarted and the command is run again

Comment: Im getting TypeError: embedBefore?.delete is not a function

Answer (score 0):

You could store the previous embed(s) (there should only be one, right, since you delete the previous ones...) in something like a `Set` if you have multiple embeds somehow and then before you send your response iterate over the Set and invoke the `delete()` method on the stored messages. [Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) the documentation for Sets in case you need further info.